# How to get projects under professors as a undergraduate?

Tags: undergraduate, projects

I am about to enter into the 3rd year of college. I am pursuing a physics major, and I want to do some kind of project work under some professor. The problem is, we have been taught only about basics of quantum mechanics and statistical mechanics so I really don't know what professor to approach. I also want to read research papers so to understand some field but the problem is I don't know where to start.

Comment: It's okay to pick a professor at random.  Just make sure you know what they work on before you contact them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am a professor of physics in the United States, and often get asked this question.  If you are looking for research experience in your department, you should write up a short document that includes

- Your contact information!
- A list of your skills - programming, soldering, 3D-printing, whatever you bring to the table.
- A statement of what sort of research you are looking for: theory or experiment,  how many hours a week, and whether or not you need to be paid for the work.
- A list your classes (you don't have to list grades or GPA).

As an instructor, if a student gave me such a document I would then shop them around to faculty who I knew worked well with undergraduates.  If you don't have a faculty contact you can send individual emails, or put paper (!) copies in mailboxes of faculty members.  Talk to seniors and graduate students to find out leads on who is a good mentor, and make an appointment to talk that professor about research.

Second, in the US, look for opportunities for Research Experience for Undergraduates (REU) programs across the country.   These summer programs take in students who have finished their Sophomore or Junior year and pay them to do research on-site. The [National Science Foundation](https://www.nsf.gov/crssprgm/reu/) runs a bunch of them; as do other agencies.

Finally, in my experience professors understand that most undergraduates are not ready to step into state-of-the-art research, but still can contribute substantively to the research effort.  We often view working with undergraduates as part of our broader effort of teaching. Some granting agencies view including undergraduates in research an important broader impact of the projects they choose to fund.   In addition, many undergraduates *can* do publishable research and I've published with some.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

I do my doctoral degree and I work a lot with undergraduate students. I think the best way is to get in touch with the PhD students and ask them if they need help.
I teach my undergraduate students the stuff my dissertation is about and they take measurements and little projects for my. For sure, in agreement with the professor. But I leand the PhD candidate is a good address to get in to touch with the working area you are interested in.

Comment: @Lacek Well, this is what I meant with teaching them. For sure, undergraduates have not much knowledge about it. But if you explain the basics in maybe a week or two, you take also the benefit when the student can help you during your thesis.

Answer (score 1):

I hope there is some professor of Physics that recognizes and respects you. Even better if you have spoken with them in the past. But it doesn't really matter what their specialty is at this stage. Talk to them about what you'd like to do and ask if they, or a colleague they can recommend, would guide you in some project.

If they don't feel able to do it themself, then it would be good if they would interface for you with another faculty member, giving some informal recommendation.

But, since you are just getting started, your research/reading need not be at an exceptionally high level. You need the basics, as you recognize, to get going. Deep study can come later.